# How make action on include xml from another activity?

Tags: android, xml, include

Hi I am working with android.I had included an xml into another xml using the code

```
<include  layout="@layout/commonlayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```

Now I want make updates on included xml file from another activity rather than the current activity.Is it possible ?? please help me, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

its not possible, if somehow its done then it creates memory-leaks, 
if want to update the 1st activity from 2nd activity, the flow will be

1. onbackpress of 2nd activity 1st activity onresume will  called. so update the UI on resume of 1st activity